# How to add a class to img rendered by imagefield?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, imagefield

I am uploading an image with Imagefield and I want to add a class to `<img src="imagefile" class="caption" />` because there is no class defined for images rendered by Imagefield.

Is this possible in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 0):

You could override the **theme_imagefield_image()** function, by copying it to your template.php **and** renaming it to MYTHEME_imagefield_image(). It'd be something like:

```
function MYTHEME_imagefield_image($file, $alt = '', $title = '', $attributes = NULL, $getsize = TRUE) {
  //
  // ... same contents as the original one, except:
  //
  $attributes['class'] = $attributes['class'] ? "{$attributes['class']} my-custom-class" : 'my-custom-class';
  $attributes = drupal_attributes($attributes);
  return '<img '. $attributes .' />';
}
```

...in your **template.php**.

And clear the cache! :>

**Edit**:

If you are using the [Imagecache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache) module, then you would overwrite the **theme_imagecache()** function instead, ending up with:

```
function MYTHEME_imagecache($presetname, $path, $alt = '', $title = '', $attributes = NULL, $getsize = TRUE, $absolute = TRUE) {
  // Check is_null() so people can intentionally pass an empty array of
  // to override the defaults completely.
  if (is_null($attributes)) {
    $attributes = array('class' => 'imagecache imagecache-'. $presetname);
  }
  if ($getsize && ($image = image_get_info(imagecache_create_path($presetname, $path)))) {
    $attributes['width'] = $image['width'];
    $attributes['height'] = $image['height'];
  }

  // These two lines are what you need 
  $custom_class = 'your-custom-class';
  $attributes['class'] = $attributes['class'] ? "{$attributes['class']} {$custom_class}" : $custom_class;

  $attributes = drupal_attributes($attributes);                         
  $imagecache_url = imagecache_create_url($presetname, $path, FALSE, $absolute);
  return '<img src="'. $imagecache_url .'" alt="'. check_plain($alt) .'" title="'. check_plain($title) .'" '. $attributes .' />';
}
```

...in your **template.php** file.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't worked, maybe because I'm using imagecache with imagefield and imagecache is overriding the output of imagefield. I am trying to put the code here but the characters limit is not allowing me. :-(

Comment: Use the [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module to find out which template/theme function is currently handling the imagefield output

Comment: Hey Himanshu, I've extended my answer to include the case where Imagecache is being used.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? 
In case you are trying to style your output for imagefield fields with css, you could just use the class of a previous div I suppose. So if your html looks something like this (mine does, using imagefield and imagecache):

```
<div class="field field-type-filefield field-field-images"> <!-- created by imagefield -->
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item odd">
      <a class="imagecache imagecache-thumbs imagecache-imagelink imagecache-thumbs_imagelink" href="http://yoursite/sites/default/files/originalFile.jpg">
        <img alt="" src="http://yoursite/sites/default/files/imagecache/thumbs/originalFile.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your css file use something like this to style your image (this example puts the images next to each other instead of below each other, creating some sort of gallery).

```
.field-field-images img
{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```